# On a Unit Circle, Determine all Values of Theta for X Trigonometric Function

Tags: trigonometry, circles

I am not sure how to solve this at all.

I am not very good at math. Please put answers in normal language as much as possible.

Instructions:

On the unit circle $[0, 2\pi$), determine all values of $\theta$ for the following trigonometric functions.

if $\sec\theta = - \sqrt{2},$  then$\ \theta = \frac{3\pi}{4}, \frac{5\pi}{4}$

How do I solve this sort of equation?

Comment: If you down-vote this, please tell me why so I know better next time.

Comment: Do you know that $\;\sec\theta=\frac1{\cos\theta}\;$ ? Well, then your first equality means $$\frac1{\cos\theta}=-\sqrt2\implies\cos\theta=-\frac1{\sqrt2}$$ Do you know where cosine equals $\;-\frac1{\sqrt2}\;$ ? For example, at $\;\theta=\frac{3\pi}4\;$ , in the second quadrant. Try to continue the short way that is left...

Comment: Oh, I see! thanks!